# How can I return a model with an ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, actionlink

I'm trying to get a model in a view and pass it to another controller but the model is null when passed to the other controller.

Controller - Here I send the model to render in my view:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Index(ReportesTabularesViewModel ModeloInput)
    {
        GetDatosTabularReportInput input = new GetDatosTabularReportInput { IdSensor = ModeloInput.sensor, FechaInicio = ModeloInput.FechaInicio, FechaFinal = ModeloInput.FechaFinal };
        ReportesTabularesViewModel Modelo = new ReportesTabularesViewModel();
        var Lista = new CaelusReporting.Datos.DatosApp().GetDatosTabularReport(input);

        var s = Modelo.Sensores;

        ViewBag.Sensores = s;
        Modelo.Datos = Lista.GroupBy(x => x.Fecha).Select(y => new DatosViewModel
        {
            Fecha = y.Key,
            EstacionSensorSensorNombre = y.First().EstacionSensorSensorNombre,
            Datos = y
        }
            );

        ViewBag.Modelo = ModeloInput;
        return PartialView(Modelo);
    }
```

View:

```html
@model CaelusReporting.Web.Models.ViewModels.Datos.ReportesTabularesViewModel
@{
    ViewData["temp"] = ViewBag.Modelo;   
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Datos.Select(y => y.EstacionSensorSensorNombre).FirstOrDefault();
    List<CaelusReporting.Sensores.Dto.SensoresDto> sensores = ViewBag.Sensores;
}


<a class="menu-bar" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu">
    <span class="bars"></span>
</a>
<div class="collapse menu" id="menu">
    <div class="list-inline">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Update", HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
        {

            <label>Sensor: </label>
            <select data-placeholder="Escoja las estaciones" class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="8" name="sensor">
                @foreach (var item in sensores.Where(x => x.estado == true))
                {
                    <option value=@item.Id>@item.nombre</option>
                }
            </select>
            <label>Fecha de Inicio: </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FechaInicio, null, new { type = "datetime-local", style = "max-width:235px; max-height:20px" })
            <label>Fecha de Final: </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FechaFinal, null, new { type = "datetime-local", style = "max-width:235px; max-height:20px" })

            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Ver" />

        }

        <a href="@Url.Action("ExportReport", "Reportes", new { DocType = "PDF" })"> Get Report in PDF</a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("ExportReport", "Reportes", new { DocType = "XLS" })"> Get Report in XLS</a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("ExportReport", "Reportes", new { DocType = "DOC" })"> Get Report in DOC</a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("ExportReport", "Reportes", new { DocType = "CSV" })"> Get Report in CSV</a>
       
       
    </div>
</div>
```

Another controller - Here I try to import report that is in:

```
  public ActionResult ExportReport(string DocType)
    {
        ReportesTabularesViewModel test = ViewData["temp"] as ReportesTabularesViewModel;

        GetDatosTabularReportInput input = new GetDatosTabularReportInput { IdSensor = test.sensor, FechaInicio = test.FechaInicio, FechaFinal = test.FechaFinal };

        var Lista = new CaelusReporting.Datos.DatosApp().GetDatosTabularReport(input);
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportess"), "Reporte.rpt"));
        rd.SetDataSource(Lista);
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        switch (DocType)
        {
            case "PDF":
                rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportess"), "Reporte.rpt"));
                try
                {
                    Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return File(stream, "application/pdf", "ReportePDF.pdf");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            case "DOC":
                rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportess"), "Reporte.rpt"));
                try
                {
                    Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.WordForWindows);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return File(stream, "application/msword", "ReporteDOC.doc");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            case "XLS":
                rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportess"), "Reporte.rpt"));
                try
                {
                    Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Excel);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return File(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "ReporteDOC.xls");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            case "CSV" :
                 rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportess"), ""));
                try
                {
                    Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.CharacterSeparatedValues);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return File(stream, "text/csv", "ReporteCSV.csv");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass ViewData between requests (actions). You need to serialize data somehow, in querysting for example. You can use `RouteValueDictionary` to do this.

you need to create Model for action `ActionResult ExportReport(string DocType)` like this:

```
public class ExportReportModel
{
    public string DocType {get; set;}
    // all fields which you required from ReportesTabularesViewModel
}
```

then your action will looks like this `ActionResult ExportReport(ExportReportModel model)` and you can render such a links:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ExportReport", "Reportes", new RouteValueDictionary(new ReportesTabularesViewModel{/*initialize object*/}))">Get  Report in PDF</a>
```

you can also use anonymous objects, but in case when you have more than 3 parameters I will organize those in some kind of structure.